# Running a standalone from WAR file

Tags: java, unix

I have a WAR file deployed on Websphere server (on unix) and I do not have the source code for it. I know that in the WAR there is a class in a pcakage com.mypackage.myclass.class which has a main that takes one argument agr0.

How do I run this class to get the output ?

Comment: What is the exact signature of the main method? Does it take just a string or an array of strings (like main methods usually do)?

Comment: @ShashankAraokar The mail method takes a string. Something like this java TestClass myid.

Comment: And where do you want to call this method from? A servlet, a controller, a JSP?...

Answer (score 0):

When that WAR file is installed, it gets expanded to a directory within the WebSphere installation.  For example, if your WAR file was *app.war* and it was installed on node *node1* within profile *baseProfile*, that directory may be:

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/baseProfile/installedApps/node1/app.war
```

Somewhere in that directory (likely in the WEB-INF/lib directory), you would find the jar file.   If the jar file was called test.jar and it in the WEB-INF/lib directory, you could run it from a command line like so:

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/bin/java -jar /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/baseProfile/installedApps/node1/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/test.jar argumentValue
```

Comment: The class is not in the Jar file but in the /WEB-INF/classes folder. I will try to find put the WEB-INF path of the extracted WAR and see if that helps.